# How do I secure my h2-console using Lambda DSL?

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

It seems spring recommends [using Lambda DSL](https://spring.io/blog/2019/11/21/spring-security-lambda-dsl) for Security Configuration.

Without using lambdas, I know how to secure my h2-console.

```
public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
        .authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/h2-console/**").authenticated()
        .anyRequest().authenticated()
        .and().formLogin()
        .and().csrf().ignoringAntMatchers("/h2-console/**")
        .and().headers().frameOptions().sameOrigin();
    return http.build();
```

Following the tutorial at the beginning, I tried the following code

```
    http
        .authorizeRequests((authz) -> authz
            .antMatchers("/h2-console/**").authenticated()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
        )
        .formLogin()
        .csrf().ignoringAntMatchers("/h2-console/**")
        .headers().frameOptions().sameOrigin();
```

and got this error

> The method csrf() is undefined for the type FormLoginConfigurer

I also tried lots of other combinations, such as

```
    http
        .authorizeRequests(a -> a.anyRequest().permitAll())
        .headers().frameOptions().sameOrigin();
```

or

```
    http
        .authorizeRequests(a -> a.anyRequest().permitAll())         
        .csrf(c - c.ignoringAntMatchers("/h2-console/**"));
```

or

```
    http
        .authorizeRequests(a -> a.anyRequest().permitAll())         
        .csrf().ignoringAntMatchers("/h2-console/**")
```

and more and more, none of them works.

How do I secure my h2-console using Lambda DSL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**TL;DR:** Use the same lambda syntax as for `authorizeRequests`:

```
http.csrf(csrf -> csrf.ignoringAntMatchers("/h2-console/**"))
```

*Details:*
You are mixing old syntax (Spring Security 5) with the new (Spring Security 6) syntax.
Old syntax: `http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("...").permitAll().and().csrf().ignoringAntMantchers("...")` is replaced with `http.authorizeRequests(a -> a.requestMatchers("...")).csrf(csrf -> csrf.ignoringAntMatchers("...))`